# Show array value in loop with twig

Tags: php, loops, twig

I want to show my array value in a twig loop. This is my array structure:

```
array(4) {
  ["image"] => NULL
  ["title"] => string(8) "My title"
  ["body"] => string(7) "My text"
  ["path"] => string(8) "/myurl/3"
}
```

I have tried this twig loop but with no luck:

```
{% for my in MyArray %}
<h3>{{ my.title }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you set the associative array's name to MyArray?

Comment: What show `{{ dump(MyArray) }}`?

Comment: @marmeladze I'm not sure what do you mean! name to MyArray?

Comment: @Federico In the question, Below of "This is my array structure..."

Comment: Then you should use `{{ MyArray.title }}`, no need for a loop.